# Customizing Section Header in Koma-script: Getting warning "Usage of deprecated command \ifstr"

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, section-titles, scrartcl, customize

I'm using `Koma-script` package for the LaTeX document.
For customizing `section` header, I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
        \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
            \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}%
            \medskip
            \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
        }%
    }{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=\bigskipamount,afterskip=1.0em]{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title with section numbering}
Some sample text goes here.

\section{Section title without section numbering}
More sample text goes here.

\end{document}
```

*Note:* Above MWE is based on the example from the `Koma-script` manual (See *Page 497 of [English Manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en)*)

---

My code is compiling successfully, but I'm getting the following `warning` in log.

> Usage of deprecated command `\ifstr'.

- Is there any alternative way to customize section header in `Koma-script` without using  `\makeatletter`?
- Is there any way to remove this deprecated command `\ifstr`?

Comment: Just an fyi, your code needs a few more things to be an MWE. It's good that it's minimal, but a MWE should begin with a document class, like `scrartcl` or `scrbook`, and it should end with an `\end{document}`. This ensures anybody can copy, paste, and run your code. Also, welcome to TeX StackExchange!

Comment: @gz839918 Thanks for the heads-up. Just updated the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show the full warning message, which is

```
Package scrbase Warning: Usage of deprecated command `\ifstr'.
(scrbase)                The command has been renamed because of a
(scrbase)                recommendation of The LaTeX Project Team.
(scrbase)                Please replace `\ifstr' by `\Ifstr' on input line 25.
```

so as it says; you can use  `\Ifstr` rather than `\ifstr`

Comment: Thanks! I was only checking the LOG tab in TeXstudio. Opened the log file and found the above log warning. So, it got solved by replacing `\ifstr' by `\Ifstr'